# How to unstack bargraph in plotly python?

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly-python

I'm using px bar plot and in my dataframe there are repeating rows which will be assigned as x to bar plot.
By default bar plots stacks them, and changing barmode doesn't help.
I want to draw them seperatly as shown in screen below. The way excel would do it.
Thank you in advance.

```
import plotly.express as px
abc=np.random.randint(1,30, 15)
df=pd.DataFrame(abc, columns=['v1'])
df['v2']=list('abc'*5)
fig = px.bar(df, x='v2',y='v1')
fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, I think it would be better to specify the x-axis as the index of the data frame and update the axis labels with the column data.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

abc=np.random.randint(1,30, 15)
df=pd.DataFrame(abc, columns=['v1'])
df['v2']=list('abc'*5)
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index,y='v1')

fig.update_xaxes(title_text='v2', tickvals=df.index, ticktext=df['v2'].tolist())
fig.show()
```

[image]